# Sorting a slice of strings based on an alphabet of substrings

Tags: arrays, string, sorting, go

I have a list of words, and a list of "letters" that is in the order I want to sort the word list in:

```golang
words    := []string{"kape","piki","na","nga","bube","babo","ninggi","baboninggi"}
alphabet := []string{"a","i","u","e","o","p","t","k","m","ng","n","b","d","g"}

expectedOrder := []string{"piki","kape","nga","na","ninggi","babo","baboninggi","bube"}
```

I have tried using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56358709) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59526238), giving each letter in `alphabet` a rank in a map, however the answer there only works when matching whole strings. Here, I need to sort by "letters", which are not necessarily 1 rune long (see "ng" above).

A rune-by-rune approach wouldn't work here either, because, as stated, the letters are not runes and aren't necessarily 1 rune long. Due to this, there is a possibility that a "letter" contains other letters as substrings, but comes first in the order (see: "nga" and "na" above. A rune-by-rune approach would say the order is `na,nga` when the letters state that the order is `nga,na`).

How can I go about this without resorting to something that's O(n^2) or worse?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can I define a custom alphabet order for comparing and sorting strings in go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53902528/how-can-i-define-a-custom-alphabet-order-for-comparing-and-sorting-strings-in-go/53906922#53906922) Yes, that answer show sorting by a custom alphabet defined by runes. To apply that to your problem, you may map multi-rune segments to single runes, perform a replace and sort that to get the order you need.

Comment: Or alternatively extend that solution to work with segments (strings) instead of single runes. It's probably easier than mapping, replacing multi-rune segments and deduce original order (or using a data structure that holds the original strings too).

Comment: @icza Mapping multi-rune segments to single runes is not an option. Any string can be both a word and an alphabet "letter", so mapping it like that is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

One method using the same concepts in the linked answers, is to create a rank specific to your words by translating them into new strings that will compare in the order you want. For convenience we'll use printable characters as the rank values to use in the string lexical comparison.

```
// rank each letter of the alphabet, using ascii characters as the value

var alphabet = strings.NewReplacer(
    "a", "a",
    "i", "b",
    "u", "c",
    "e", "d",
    "o", "e",
    "p", "f",
    "t", "g",
    "k", "h",
    "m", "i",
    "ng", "j",
    "n", "k",
    "b", "l",
    "d", "m",
    "g", "n",
)
```

You can translate the words on demand for each comparison

```
sort.Slice(words, func(i, j int) bool {
    return alphabet.Replace(words[i]) < alphabet.Replace(words[j])
})
```

or if you want to trade memory for comparison time, you can pre-translate all the words into a new string, and sort based on those:

```
translated := make([]string, 0, len(words))
for _, word := range words {
    translated = append(translated, alphabet.Replace(word))
}
sort.Slice(translated, func(i, j int) bool {
    less := translated[i] < translated[j]
    // swap the actual words slice in conjunction with the translated slice
    if less {
        words[i], words[j] = words[j], words[i]
    }
    return less
})
```

https://go.dev/play/p/h2rBvsS_UI-